# How to fix symfony error: Cannot autowire argument $request of "App\Controller\ArticleController::create()"?

Tags: php, symfony

Tell me please, How to fix symfony error:

> Cannot autowire argument $request of
>   "App\Controller\ArticleController::create()": it references class
>   "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request" but no such service exists.

Controller:

```
use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Form\ArticleType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/article/create", name="creates_article")
 */
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article();

    $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('article/form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Log: Channel - Request

```
Matched route "creates_article".
{
"route": "creates_article",
"route_parameters": {
    "_route": "creates_article",
    "_controller": "App\\Controller\\ArticleController::create"
},
"request_uri": "http://symfony.loc/article/create",
"method": "GET"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, you've used wrong `Request` class namespace.

It should be :

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
```

instead of

```
Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request
```

So try with:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

Example in Symfony docs: 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function index(Request $request, $firstName, $lastName)
{
    $page = $request->query->get('page', 1);

    // ...
}
```